# Linq update with explicit operator

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am trying to do an update with linq using an explict cast and the changes arent submitting.

Here is the code

```
Image update = db.Images.Where(i => i.ImageId == imageWithChanges.ImageId).SingleOrDefault();

update = (Image)imageWithChanges;

db.SubmitChanges();
```

I have an explicit operator in my image class.  Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: This needs more definition, starting with the declaration of imageWithChanges.  Also, can you use an assignment to change the values of a linq to sql class?  I think you have to go property by property and make the changes (not sure though).

Comment: Cheers Nick.  My imageWithChanges is my domain object which has updated values in it.  I basically get the Image object from the database and then cast my domain object whch has the changes to the database image object.  I was hoping I didnt have to loop through property by property.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
update = (Image)imageWithChanges;
```

is not changing anything. It's merely swapping the thing the variable *update* points at. If you want to actually change the image, you'd probably have to copy each property from *imageWithChanges* to *update*.

Another way you can do this, is to attach *imageWithChanges* to db.Images and say it was a modified instance:

```
db.Images.Attach((Image)imageWithChanges, true); // true means "it's modified"
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks Ruben, but when I add the attach it gives me the error "An entity can only be attached as modified without original state if it declares a version member or does not have an update check policy."

Answer (score 0):

You say you got it fixed, but don't tell How.

For all others that will read this, I agree with Ruben, you have to Attach it.  The error it gives you is valid, you have to either handle concurrency checking (with timestamp or version number) or let last in wins (by setting UpdateCheck to false for all your entity's properties).

Comment: sorry, thought I had this fixed.  Here is my code 

Image updatedImage = (Image)image;
               
                using (OrebroDataContext db = new OrebroDataContext())
                {
                    db.Images.Attach(updatedImage, true);
                    db.Products.AttachAll(updatedImage.Products,true);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }

I have products hanging off my image object, but I keep getting a key in use error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Folks, I have definitely got it fixed.  The problem was I had forgot to  add a timestamp column to one of my database tables.  Once I did that everything worked.  Doh.  Cheers for everyones help